# Buying DC motors with fitting gears

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I want to try a little project with an arduino controlled crossbow turret. Therefore I need some motors to move the turret and gears. Since this is my first try on such a project I am very unsure on how to find the needed DC motors and gears that are usable with those motors. I need a little guidance for what motors I am actually looking for. The motors should only move the rotation of the crossbow (horizontal and vertical). I already found some motors with a torque stall of 8.5 kg/cm which I think is enough to move the turrent. But I still do not know what gears I can buy for that. I could not read anything up that tells me that gears are universally usable for every kind of motor or how to attach gears to motors actually.

Comment: have you considered using hobby servos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting a servo you need to know the torque and the load profile. Not all types of actuators are equally suitable to become a robot component. Steppers and servo motors seem to have the qualities essential to build a robot. Some of the servos come with a integrated gera and controller. That could make the whole RD a bit easier and MPV production seriously faster. You can get some insights from this [How to select a motor for a robot](https://rozum.com/selecting-a-servo/)